# How do I prevent players from editing armor stands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a kit PvP map. In the map I want the players to see different kits/classes represented by armor stands with various equipment on them, to represent the kit. The players will be in adventure mode, and I want to know how to stop them from stealing the items from the armor stands. I know about the `{Invulnerable:1b}` tag to make the players unable to break the armor stands, but I do not know of a tag that makes the armor stands unable to be edited (taking off armor, weapons etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank Yes, I have tried to solve this myself, playing with different tags, like I said the {Invulnerable:1b} tag.

Comment: So what research have you done to prevent the editing? That seems to be the core issue, from what I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `DisabledSlots` tag. To make an armor stand that players cannot change, use the tag `{DisabledSlots:2096896}`. Note that the number `2096896` is the sum of the flag numbers.

Refer to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2czu1p/armorstand_disabledslots_flag_system/) on Reddit that lists out the flag numbers for slots that can be disabled. To use multiple flags, use the sum of the desired flag numbers.

Comment: The list is also in the wiki, that's probably more up-to-date in case anything about this changes in the future: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/chunk_format (section about about stands)

Comment: @54D thanks for the answer! And thanks for not being like Frank...